# Checkbox event that fires AFTER the value has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox, observablecollection

I'm creating my very first wpf application.  At this moment I need an event that fires AFTER the value of a checkbox has changed, so checked and unchecked are out of the picture :-(

I have a datagrid, binded to an observable collection.  In this datagrid I have a column with checkboxes (binded to a property in the observ. col.).
A textbox on the form shows the 'total value' that is the sum of the values of all checked items.  So when a checkbox is checked/unchecked I need to recalculate the total value.  To do this I loop over the items of the observ. col.  However, when I attach the events 'checked' and 'unchecked'.  The total value gets calculated first.  Then the check-value is changed.

Is there a way to have the check value changed and after that fire an event?

Thx,

Jan

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="305" Margin="105,137,0,0" Name="GrdReceivings" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="850" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectedCellsChanged="GrdReceivings_SelectedCellsChanged" MouseDoubleClick="GrdReceivings_MouseDoubleClick" IsEnabled="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn MinWidth="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Selected}" >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnCheck"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnUncheck"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
...
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: So when a checkbox is checked/unchecked I need to recalculate the total value. To do this I loop over the items of the observ. col. However, when I attach the events 'checked' and 'unchecked'. The total value gets calculated first. Then the check-value is changed.  This means that the shown value is never correct.  I need it to be correct.

Comment: then you can do opposite..like if it comes out to be checked, do what should have happened if unchecked..because  you unchecked it but it returned checked...yo can try the click event also

Comment: Not really possible.  Say I have 5 items.  I check (or uncheck) one of them.  that means that normally I will have 4 items where the value gets correctly summed and 1 item that gets incorrectly summed.  If I turn the process around I will have 4 items incorrectly summed and 1 item correctly summed.  I need 5 items correctly summed.  It also seems that I cannot know which checkbox of which item was checked / unchecked since they are in a datagrid.

Comment: did you check what happens on click event what value does it return or something event like after click

Comment: its a bit strange that on the time of event the value is still old... tried with normal checkbox (not in grid): first it is checked/unchecked and after that the event fires...

Comment: @sickUnit try it with a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`...

Comment: @JanSolo you should calculate values of only those checkboxes which are clicked , not all

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in order to get the binding updated immediately:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
    Binding="{Binding Path=Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this the wrong way around for WPF. Instead of looking at the UI controls, look at the data. You said that you were binding the `Checkbox` controls to a property of the `ObservableCollection`... I'm guessing that you meant a property of the object *inside* the `ObservableCollection` and not the collection itself.

So in your view model or code behind, update your total value when the property that is bound to the `Checkbox` control is changed. This way, it will have the updated value every time.

Comment: See `Binding="{Binding Path=Selected}"` in the question's XAML. OP wrote "binded to a property in the observ. col.".

Comment: I tried this and it works almost.  The selection value gets updated not when I check/uncheck the checkbox, but when I select another record in the grid after I change the checkbox value.  Is there a way to force an update to happen instantly?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about `DataGrid`s, but you could try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding on the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.

Comment: My point was your "I'm guessing that you meant a property of the object inside the ObservableCollection and not the collection itself", which obviously is the `Selected` property. So you could directly refer to that property in your answer.

Comment: this did solve the problem:

<DataGridCheckBoxColumn MinWidth="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

Comment: @Sheridan You chould edit your answer (or write another one) and add the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` solution. It might be helpful for others, which may not read through these comments.

Comment: Jan, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer so that other users know. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Thx to Sheridan & Clemens, it did the trick.  To formulate the good answer:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="305" Margin="105,137,0,0" Name="GrdReceivings" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="850" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectedCellsChanged="GrdReceivings_SelectedCellsChanged" MouseDoubleClick="GrdReceivings_MouseDoubleClick" IsEnabled="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn MinWidth="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

then, in the observable collection, on the setter, calculate the value.