# WPF checkboxcolumn— on checkbox value changed, do something

Tags: c#, wpf

What I want to do is enable a button when a checkbox in a DataGridCheckBoxColumn is checked.  I did some research and found this stackoverflow below.  I found that placing the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the column should do the trick, but when I place a breakpoint on my property, it does not get called.

[Checkbox event that fires AFTER the value has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013426/checkbox-event-that-fires-after-the-value-has-changed)

Here is my XAML code that I have:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="18" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyProperty, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Verify" Width="1*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="PalletID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="2*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my view model, my property is this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Objects.MyClass> _myProperty;
public ObservableCollection<Objects.MyClass> MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        _myProperty= value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

where MyClass is a simple class containing three properties:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public bool Verified { get; set; }
public bool Status { get; set; }


public MyClass(string id, bool currentStatus)
{
    Id = id;
    Verified = currentStatus;
    Status = false;//Set to false initially to deselect checkbox.
}
```

Is there something that I am missing?  From what I gathered online, the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the checkbox column is what should allow me to view when the checkbox value changes.  Any help would be great.

Comment: So just to verify: your property **Status** is never hit?

Comment: How do you know that the property is not called?

Comment: If I place a breakpoint on "Status" in my class, it does get returned; and the property is updated in the view.  However, the problem is the view does not see the updated value.  I know this is not occurring because I placed a breakpoint on my property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working mate. Just add the button and bind the Status property to the button's IsEnabled property.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="18" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyProperty, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Verify" Width="1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="PalletID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="2*"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Status}">I am a button</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  The button that I was binding to was outside of the datagrid, but what you supplied worked in my app.